# Add smoothness between changing images with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code that changes the image when a user rolls over a map area on my United States map. It is working perfectly. But I want the the images to have a smooth appearance and then a gradual fade away. What do I need to add to this code? Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//set off state 
var nav_off = "/images/state-map.png";

// functions for over and off
function over(image) {
    $("#main-nav").attr("src", image);
}
function off() {
    $("#main-nav").attr("src", nav_off);
}

$("#imagemap area").hover(
    function () {
        var button = $(this).attr("id");
        over("/images/state-" + button + ".png");
    },
    function () {
        off();
    });

});
```

Comment: have you tried $("#main-nav").fadeIn(); and $("#main-nav").fadeOut(); ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using jQuery's fadeOut/fadeIn effect.
Perhaps something like this:

```
function over(image) {
    $("#main-nav").fadeOut(function () {
        $(this).attr("src", image).fadeIn();
    });
}

function off() {
    $("#main-nav").fadeOut(function () {
        $(this).attr("src", nav_off).fadeIn();
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

[CSS transitions](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/) are an alternative way of handling this. There's a good tutorial (and demo) [here](http://www.mightymeta.co.uk/573/fading-button-background-images-with-css3-transitions/).

Answer (score 0):

you can see the effects API .using fadeIn() fadeOut() functions
http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/